# Matplotlib xaxis.set_major_formatter doesn't understand year

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

### Information

I have the below pd.dataframe which is plotted with

```
ax = dfPivot.plot()
plt.grid()
plt.grid(which='minor')
plt.show()

In [4]: dfPivot.index
Out[4]:
DatetimeIndex(['2020-05-26 12:00:33', '2020-05-26 12:02:13',
               '2020-05-26 12:03:53', '2020-05-26 12:05:33',
               '2020-05-26 12:07:13', '2020-05-26 12:08:53',
               '2020-05-26 12:10:33', '2020-05-26 12:12:13',
               '2020-05-26 12:13:53', '2020-05-26 12:15:33',
               ...
               '2020-05-29 09:08:53', '2020-05-29 09:10:33',
               '2020-05-29 09:12:13', '2020-05-29 09:13:53',
               '2020-05-29 09:15:33', '2020-05-29 09:17:13',
               '2020-05-29 09:18:53', '2020-05-29 09:20:33',
               '2020-05-29 09:22:13', '2020-05-29 09:23:53'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='DateTime', length=2499, freq=None)
```

It works it's ok.

[image: Plot working without]

---

### Problem

I have a problem when I format the X axis with:

```
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S") # tried with "%x %X" or any other combination, failed.
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
```

python drops a:

```
  rom_ordinalf
      dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix).replace(tzinfo=UTC) ValueError: year 4354626 is out of range
```

I don't understand which is being treated different when I use the set_major_formatter(). 
I tought that this was only aesthetic change but seems to go deeper.

I think that matplotlib is "trying" to find and american type date on my pd.datetime64[ns] and failed but don't know how to procede.

Thanks

Comment: Try plotting in pure matplotlib rather than calling df.plot. Pandas uses different conversion and locators.

Comment: Direct matplotlib worked. 
I'll open a ticket on the pandas.dataframe.plot() github about this issue.